# Clearing cache takes "long time"

Tags: 8, console

I am absolutely new in Drupal. I am trying to set up my first "Hello world" module and I am playing with it.
Every time I clear cache using Drupal Console, it takes 15 seconds, which is an eternity for me.

Is this normal, or did I need to change setting?

This is the output of `drupal site:status`.

```
 Drupal                         8.3.2
 Access to update.php           Protected
 Configuration files            Protected
 Cron maintenance tasks         Last run 41 minutes 54 seconds ago
 Database system                MySQL, MariaDB, Percona Server, or equivalent
 Database system version        5.5.5-10.1.21-MariaDB
 Database updates               Up to date
 Drupal core update status      Not secure! (version 8.7.0 available)
 Entity/field definitions       Up to date
 File system                    Writable (public download method)
 GD library                     bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
 GD library PNG support         bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
 Image toolkit                  gd

 Module and theme update status Out of date

 Node Access Permissions        Disabled
 PHP                            7.1.1 (more information)
 PHP extensions                 Enabled
 PHP memory limit               128M
 PHP OPcode caching             Enabled
 Random number generation       Successful
 Search index progress          100% (0 remaining)

 Trusted Host Settings          Not enabled
 Unicode library                PHP Mbstring Extension
 Update notifications           Enabled
 Upload progress                Not enabled

Web server
 Hash salt                      6X0M4mm-6Ui1Sgovc-emqgqvm2nJ1Ug-fYQYnJfxPniHHwdYMMcBHRBt1xwRtGMRRg7XbK1G3A
 Drupal Console                 1.8.0

 Database connection
 Driver              mysql
 Host                localhost
 Database connection dru
 Port                3306
 Username            root
 Connection          mysql//root:@localhost:3306/dru

 Themes
 commands.site.status.messages.theme_default bartik
 commands.site.status.messages.theme_admin   seven

 Directories
 Site root directory      C:\xampp\htdocs\dru
 Site temporary directory C:\xampp\tmp
 Default theme directory  /core/themes/bartik
 Admin theme directory    /core/themes/seven
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, WAMP is not a good environment for Drupal 8. Use a different OS in a virtual machine. Either a Linux VM built from scratch or by a tool like [Drupal VM](https://www.drupalvm.com/), or a docker based tool like [DDEV](https://github.com/drud/ddev), [Docksal](https://docksal.io/), and [Lando](https://github.com/lando/lando).

Which one to choose would be opinion based. Consider not only performance, but also that debugging is most effective, when the dev environment is as close to production as possible.

Comment: Thank you for reply. You know, it is very very frustrating, that the basic Drupal site is loading so slowly in local environment, administration is slow and even such simple instruction like clear cache is slow. 
I am trying to learn Drupal, so I will debug frequently, doing mistakes on purpose and so on.. That's why any quick tool would be very handy...

Comment: Lando is the best I've tried, well to be honest I haven't tried all the other ones listed here, but I can't imagine any of them beating Lando in terms of setup easiness.